# Template function with template arguments or typename

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I am creating a template class that contains a vector of numerical data (can be int, float, double, etc). And it has one operation, which calls `std::abs()` on the data. Something like the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>


template<typename T> class MyData
{
public:
   std::vector<T> data;
   MyData<T> my_abs() const;

};


template<typename T>
MyData<T> MyData<T>::my_abs() const
{
    MyData<T> output;
    output.data.reserve(data.size());
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
    {
        output.data.push_back(std::abs(*it));
    }
    return output;
}


int main()
{
    MyData<double> A;
    A.data = std::vector<double>(10, -1.0);

    MyData<double> test = A.my_abs();

    for (auto el : test.data)
    {
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works correctly for types such as int, float, double. I also want to be able to use this class for types such as `std::complex<double>`.

Looking around I found that I could use template template arguments:

```
template<template<typename> class T, typename U> class MyData
{
public:
   std::vector<T<U>> data;
   MyData<U> my_abs() const;

};


template<template<typename> class T, typename U>
MyData<U> MyData<T<U>>::my_abs() const
{
    MyData<U> output;
    output.data.reserve(data.size());
    typename std::vector<T<U>>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
    {
        output.data.push_back(std::abs(*it));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The previous code does not work as my template class expects two arguments,

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
MyData<U> abs() const;
       ^
```

Ideally I would like something like the previous code. In which the `my_abs()` function returns the type of the template argument passed to my template. E.g if I use a `std::complex<double>` then my main function could look something like:

```
int main()
{
    MyData<std::complex<double>> A;
    A.data = std::vector<std::complex<double>>(10, std::complex<double>(-1.0, -1.0));

    MyData<double> test = A.my_abs();

    for (auto el : test.data)
    {
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure how this can be achieved (or if it is even possible using the same template class).

Comment: Just specialize your 1st version for a type like `std::complex<double>` maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the return type of `std::abs(T)` in your declaration.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>

template<typename T> class MyData
{
public:
   std::vector<T> data;
   using abs_type = decltype(std::abs(std::declval<T>()));
   auto my_abs() -> MyData<abs_type> const;
};

template<typename T>
auto MyData<T>::my_abs() -> MyData<abs_type> const
{
    MyData<abs_type> output;
    output.data.reserve(data.size());
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++)
    {
        output.data.push_back(std::abs(*it));
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    MyData<std::complex<double>> A;
    A.data = std::vector<std::complex<double>>(10, std::complex<double>(-1.0, -1.0));

    auto test = A.my_abs();

    for (auto el : test.data)
    {
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your specialization in this way

```
template<template<typename> class T, typename U>
class MyData<T<U>> // <----- note the <T<U>>
{
public:
   std::vector<T<U>> data;
   MyData<U> my_abs() const;    
};
```

Comment: Why is a specialization required? His original template works for `std::complex<double>` as well.

Comment: @user2296177 - because the OP need to extract the `U` type (the `double` part) form `T<U>` to construct the `MyData<U>` return type for `my_abs()`

Comment: @downvoter - please, can you explain what is wrong in my answer?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter and I don't see anything wrong with this approach other than might be more verbose than others.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a class for this, a template function is sufficient. You can give an `abs` function to your template function, e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename F> std::vector<T> my_abs(const std::vector<T> &in, F abs) {
    std::vector<T> out;
    for (auto &i: in) {
        out.push_back(abs(i));
    }

    return out;
}
```

calling this as

```
std::vector<int> res = my_abs(in, special_abs);
```

and if you have different types for input and output, you can parameterize on `T` and `U`.

---

As @Jarod42 already noted, this doesn't work for overloaded functions like `std::abs`.
You can work around this by giving a lambda as the second argument, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> res = my_abs(in, [](const auto& e) { return std::abs(e);});
```

Another workaround is to explicitly select the appropriate `abs` by casting to the proper type

```
std::vector<int> res = my_abs(in, static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::abs));
```

Comment: As `std::abs` has overload, `my_abs(in, std::abs);` won't compile.

Comment: You might do `my_abs(in, [](const auto& e) { return std::abs(e);});`

Comment: For my application the class is required, as the abs function is only a one of several operations that can be done on MyData. Because of that it needs to use the internal type of the class.